# Python Base64 print problem

Tags: python, string

I have a base64 encoded string

When I decode the string this way:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode("XH13fXM=")
'\\}w}s'
```

**The output is fine.**

But when i use it like this:

```
>>> d = base64.b64decode("XH13fXM=")
>>> print d
\}w}s
```

**some characters are missing**

Can anyone advise ?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a matter of presentation:

```
>>> '\\}w}s'
'\\}w}s'
>>> print(_, len(_))
\}w}s 5
```

This string has 5 characters. When you use it in code you need to escape backslash, or use raw string literals:

```
>>> r'\}w}s'
'\\}w}s'
>>> r'\}w}s' == '\\}w}s'
True
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `print` a string, the characters in the string are output.  When the interactive shell shows you the value of your last statement, it prints the `__repr__` of the string, not the string itself.  That's why there are single-quotes around it, and your backslash has been escaped.

No characters are missing from your second example, those are the 5 characters in your string.  The first example has had characters add to make the output a legal Python string literal.

If you want to use the print statement and have the output look like the first example, then use:

```
print repr(d)
```